# How can I implement field-level permissions for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

In MySQL I can grant permissions to update specific fields:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE (col_Eagle) ON db_ANIMAL.tb_BIRD to 'JOHNNY'@'localhost';
```

MongoDB only has "read" or "readWrite" roles:

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "JOHNNY",
      pwd: "pass",
      roles: [
        { 
          role: "read", # or readWrite??
          db: "db_ANIMAL" 
        }
      ]
    }
)
```

How can I limit update permissions to specific fields in MongoDB 3.4?

Comment: MongoDB has no support for this, the smallest they have is [per collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/). You will have to implement this yourself in your application layer if you really need it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.4, the granularity of the built-in access control only goes as far as [Collection-Level Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/collection-level-access-control/).

For example, you could create a user-defined role limiting privileges for a collection:

```
privileges: [
  { resource: { db: "db_ANIMAL", collection: "tb_BIRD" },  actions: [ "find", "update" ] }
]
```

For limiting read-only access to a subset of collection data, you could consider using the new [Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) functionality in MongoDB 3.4 or implementing [Field Level Redaction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/implement-field-level-redaction/) using the `$redact` aggregation stage (MongoDB 2.6+).

If you need more granular access control for field-level updates you will currently have to implement this in your API or application code.

There are a few relevant feature requests you may want to watch/upvote in the MongoDB issue tracker:

- [SERVER-648: Document level access control](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-648)
- [SERVER-27698: Materialized views](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-27698)

Answer (score 2):

I just created a [post in MongoDB's forums](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/restrict-users-access-to-other-users-documents-without-middleware/117963) on this subject and a MongoDB employee pointed me towards the solution.

To implement field-level permission for *end users* (users interacting with an app that accesses the database directly), this can now be done using **MongoDB Realm**, as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/query-roles/).