# MERN stack MongoDB Permission and Access Level Setup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, access-control, role-based-access-control

I am creating a MERN Stack application. I am very confused about access permission to keys in my mongoDb schemas. I came from Firebase which allowed you to set up node level read/write access controls in the Firebase rules.
Below is an example I wish to achieve.

There are 3 Schemas:

```
UserSchema : {
id : id,
name : String ,
email : String 
}

CompanySchema : {
createdByID : ref : userSchema,
team : [ref : userSchema],
Id : id,
name : String,
description : String,
}

SubDivisionSchema : {
createdById : ref : userSchema ,
company : ref : CompanySchema ,
name : String ,
calendar : [Object]
}
```

The flow that occurs is that a `Company` hires `Users`. They then deploy these users to subdivisions. By default all new hires at a company are of role type `Team`. The owner of the company can elevate their permissions to one of the permission below.

**OWNER , ADMIN , HR , TEAM**

Below are what these permissions can do:

*Owner* : CRUD on Business and CRUD on all subdivisions

*Admin* : RU on Business and CRUD on all subdivisions

*HR* : All read and only allowed to update the `team` on Business and all R and only allowed to update calendar on all subdivisions

*Team* : Only read on some fields on Business. Only read on subdivision they are assigned to.

I will also have subdivision access levels but if I can just understand how to give key-level access control rather than document-level access control, I think I can work from there.

Thank you!

Comment: In mongodb granularity of permissions is only up to collection level, see also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545978/how-can-i-implement-field-level-permissions-for-mongodb